# Why I am getting error 'Server rejected the 1 private key' error on setting up ssh-slave Docker image

Tags: ssh, authentication, jenkins

I am running both Jenkins master and slave as Docker containers by using jenkins/jenkins:lts and jenkins/ssh-slave image on Ubuntu. Following are the steps:

- Ran `ssh-keygen` inside the jenkins-master container (`docker exec -it container_id bash`) to generate the ssh keys
- Added the generated public key to authorized_keys file inside ssh-slave container using dockerfile
- Added private key inside Jenkins credentials as per this [link](https://devopscube.com/setup-slaves-on-jenkins-2/)

I have looked at many questions related to this issue on Stack Overflow but I am stuck with following error:

```
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ###.##.#.#:22.
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] SSH host key matches key in Known Hosts file. Connection will be allowed.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for jenkins (credentialId:worker-ssh/method:publickey)
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[02/08/19 20:31:06] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[02/08/19 20:31:06] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

**Slave Template in Jenkins:**

**Name**: jenkins-worker

**Usage**: Use this node as much as possible

**Launch method**: Launch agent via SSH

**Hostname**: my ip extracted from ifconfig

**Host key verification startegy**: known hosts file verification strategy (`.ssh/known_hosts` contains entry for host ip provided)

Dockerfile for ssh-slave

```
    #Docker version 18.09.1
    FROM jenkins/ssh-slave
    COPY /.ssh/id_rsa.pub /.ssh/authorized_keys
    RUN chmod 744 /.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: "I added my private key in the credentials to ssh into the slave" - you need to add your *public* key to the authorized_keys file on the slave, not your private key.

Comment: I have added my public key in authorized_key folder at slave and private key as a credential to ssh on Jenkins. I have updated my question with clear description.

Comment: `chmod 744 on .ssh/authorized_keys` I think would be bad. ssh will not use keys from files if permissions are too open. Change to 600. rw-------

Answer (score 1):

`chmod 744 on .ssh/authorized_keys` I think would be bad. ssh will not use keys from files if permissions are too open.

Change permissions to 600. rw-------

```
   permissions of 744 == rwxr-xr-x   ==  read permissions for world and group

   permissions of 600 == rw-------   ==  read/write permissions for owner user only
```